# Get Active and Registered customer from Mysql Table

Tags: mysql

I have a db table `crm_accounts` in which having a field `account_status`.

Status could be `Active` or `Registered`.

I want the count of active customers and registered customers.

I need e.g. **ActiveCount=30 and RegisteredCount=40.**

Please help me to write the query.

Comment: `select account_status, count(*) from crm_accounts group by account_status where account_status in ( 'Active', 'Registered' );`

Comment: In single query only. I can get the result by writing different queries.

Comment: @amdixon: Thanks for the help. But Its showing "Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where account_status in ('Active','Registered')' at line 1". Not getting whats the exact issue in query.

Comment: Yes got it. The sequence of Order by is wrong.Thanks !! @amdixon: Please correct the sequence from your answer.

Comment: select account_status, count(*) from crm_accounts where account_status in ( 'Active', 'Registered' ) group by account_status ; where clause needs to come first is all

Answer (score 0):

This one also work:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM crm_accounts 
WHERE (account_status = 'Active' OR account_status = 'Registered');
```

Comment: should be `.. = 'Active' OR ..`. and will only give you one total count

Comment: Its showing me total count of records. But i need e.g. ActiveCount=30 and RegisteredCount=40.

Comment: @amdixon but he wants both so i used `AND`

Comment: account_status is either 'Active' 'Registered' or some other value. it cannot be both at once.. AND will return 0 rows

Comment: @amdixon i did it `OR`.. but now OP wants something else.. :)